# Wordpress Astra free theme header

Tags: css, wordpress, header, themes

I need a help with custom code to edit Astra theme header. Padding and margin. how can i do it? I'm not using astra pro. I tried to add code to style.css but not working.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). and update your question to include the *relevant* code in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you have tried already to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use "additional styles": go to admin panel - Appearance - Customize - Additional CSS.